# Geopoint constructor can not be resolved in Android Studio when using intValue of 2 doubles

Tags: java, android

In the following creation of a GeoPoint both

> latitude.intValue()

and

> longitude.intValue()

are underlined in red in Android Studio

```
 Double latitude = location.getLatitude()* 1E6;
 Double longitude = location.getLongitude() * 1E6;

 Barcode.GeoPoint point = new Barcode.GeoPoint(latitude.intValue(),longitude.intValue());
```

Can someone tell me what I´m doing wrong here?

PS: These are my Imports

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Location;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode.GeoPoint;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

Comment: Have you included the required libraries, if any, for instance if you are using AppCompat Library, you should use methods and classes that are also in the compat library

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
 Barcode.GeoPoint point = new Barcode.GeoPoint(Integer.valueOf(latitude),Integer.valueOf(longitude);
```

or you can use like this:

```
public static GeoPoint coordinatesToGeoPoint(double[] coords) {
    if (coords.length > 2) {
        return null;
    }
    if (coords[0] == Double.NaN || coords[1] == Double.NaN) {
        return null;
    }
    final int latitude = (int) (coords[0] * 1E6);
    final int longitude = (int) (coords[1] * 1E6);
    return new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
}
```

and other simple way is:

GeoPoint coordinates are based in microdegrees (degrees * 1e6)

```
float lat = -23.4456f;
float lng = 45.44334f;
GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lng * 1E6));
```

Comment: I tried all ways and this one: `Barcode.GeoPoint newPoint = new Barcode.GeoPoint((int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1E6), (int)(loc.getLongitude() * 1E6));` But I still have the same problem.

Comment: Is the GeoPoint Synthax I´m trying to apply here deprecated?

Comment: which library you are using.. ? i think you should follow @Cool Guy comment

Comment: other-wise used Geofence.., here is best example i found  https://www.raywenderlich.com/103540/geofences-googleapiclient